# botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the PutObject operation

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I have created the custom scrapy pipeline for wasabi s3 and it is working fine json file getting uploaded but I am getting this one error `botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the PutObject operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.` even though I am providing valid access key I have tried uploading a random json file using terminal and boto3 that was also working without any error. Also created policies with `WasabiFullAccess` and `AmazonS3FullAccess`

My pipeline:

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.exporters import JsonItemExporter
import boto3


class JsonWriterPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.items_list = []

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        pipeline = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return pipeline

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        self.file = open("%s_items.json" % spider.name, "wb")
        self.exporter = JsonItemExporter(self.file)
        self.exporter.encoding = "utf-8"
        self.exporter.start_exporting()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        self.file.close()
        s3 = boto3.resource(
            "s3",
            endpoint_url="https://s3.ap-northeast-1.wasabisys.com",
            aws_access_key_id="ACCESS_KEY_ID",
            aws_secret_access_key="SECRET_ACCESS_KEY",
        )
        boto_test_bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
        boto_test_bucket.upload_file("%s_items.json" % spider.name, f"{spider.name}")
```

Here is the traceback error from scrapy logs:

```
2022-10-31 03:50:18 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] ERROR: Error storing json feed (120 items) in: s3://brownfashions/brown_fashion_json/brown_fashion_json_2022-10-30T22-50-00.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zerox/BrownFashions/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/twisted/python/threadpool.py", line 244, in inContext
    result = inContext.theWork()  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
  File "/home/zerox/BrownFashions/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/twisted/python/threadpool.py", line 260, in <lambda>
    inContext.theWork = lambda: context.call(  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
  File "/home/zerox/BrownFashions/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 117, in callWithContext
    return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/zerox/BrownFashions/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 82, in callWithContext
    return func(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/zerox/BrownFashions/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scrapy/extensions/feedexport.py", line 196, in _store_in_thread
    self.s3_client.put_object(
  File "/home/zerox/BrownFashions/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 507, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/zerox/BrownFashions/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 943, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the PutObject operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

Anyone here know or any idea why I am getting this error and how to overcome this? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe have it print the ACCESS_KEY_ID before trying to connect? May help figure out why the key isn't accepted here.

Comment: also take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43907689/boto3-error-the-aws-access-key-id-you-provided-does-not-exist-in-our-records

Comment: I have tried with session also but same error and session = boto3.Session(profile_name='wasabi') also didn't worked

Comment: I print out the ACCESS_KEY_ID before connecting it was get printed ok

Comment: You'll note the stack trace doesn't involve the posted code at all.  No doubt scrapy is creating S3FeedStorage object without your endpoint, and AWS (not Wasabi) is returning the error.  You'll need to specify the [AWS_ENDPOINT_URL](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?highlight=AWS_ENDPOINT_URL#aws-endpoint-url) setting.

Comment: you mean I should put `AWS_ENDPOINT_URL = "https://s3.ap-northeast-1.wasabisys.com"` in the settings.py, right?